# Firebasedata store and data retreival error

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the following error while trying to retrieve data using Python. I get the following stacktrace when going to retrieve it. Please also tell me how to store such data using python code. Currently I am storing without code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 3, in <module>
    result = firebase.get('/varnika-c226a', None)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/firebase.py", line 274, in get
    return make_get_request(endpoint, params, headers, connection=connection)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/firebase.py", line 38, in make_get_request
    response = connection.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='varnika-c226a.firebaseio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /varnika-c226a/.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 302 Found',)))
varnika@varnika-Inspiron-N5110:~/Downloads/python-firebase-master$ python data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data.py", line 4, in <module>
    result = firebase.get('/varnika-c226a', None)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/firebase.py", line 274, in get
    return make_get_request(endpoint, params, headers, connection=connection)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/Downloads/python-firebase-master/firebase/firebase.py", line 38, in make_get_request
    response = connection.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/varnika/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='varnika-c226a.firebaseio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /varnika-c226a/.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 302 Found',)))
```

the code that i am using is :

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://varnika-c226a.firebaseio.com/', None)
result = firebase.get('/varnika-c226a', None)
print result
print firebase
```

Comment: Please add the code used to store the string in firebase.

Comment: I don't have a code for storing. If you have please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few errors here. The one that you are getting above has to do with you not being able to connect to your firebase instance as described below:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='varnika-c226a.firebaseio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /varnika-c226a/.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 302 Found',)))
```

The second one is that you don't seem to be sure how you are storing data in firebase. This is important because you cannot be sure that your data is at `'/varnika-c226a'` when you go to retrieve it in `result = firebase.get('/varnika-c226a', None)`.

Hope this helps!